# How can I use Type Augmentation in Spartacus 2.1?

Tags: angular, typescript, spartacus-storefront

The spartacus documentation about Module/type augmentation says it's supported in spartacus 2.1.
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/type-augmentation/#page-title

But when I try to extend the ConsentTemplate interface

```
import { ConsentTemplate } from '@spartacus/core';

declare module '@spartacus/core' {
  interface ConsentTemplate {
    documentUrl?: string;
  }
}
```

I get this error => `error TS2339: Property 'documentUrl' does not exist on type 'ConsentTemplate'.`

Is it possible to use type augmentation in Spartacus 2.1? And if so how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Type Augmentation is supported in Spartacus 2.1. I tested it in my app.module.ts.

[image]

Then in my application code I can see the new extended field "documentUrl" from Visual Studio Code field autocompletion list and use it as other standard fields.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I do get the intellisense on objects of the ConsentTemplate type. But my compiler throws this error nevertheless:


ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for './src/common/typings/consent.module.ts'.
src/modules/consent/containers/consent-container/consent-container.component.ts:77:36 - error TS2339: Property 'documentUrl' does not exist on type 'ConsentTemplate'.

77       `<a href="${consentTemplate?.documentUrl}" target="_blank">${consentTemplate.description}</a>`
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~